# How to access Suite Variables in RIDE

Tags: python, robotframework

Can you please help me to know how to access suite variables in RIDE after setting them using `Set Suite Variable` from the `BuiltIn` Library.

For example the session id created by Create Session used in user keyword needs to be accessed across all the test cases in Test suite.This is my use case.

Comment: When you say "in RIDE", are you writing a RIDE plugin or editing the RIDE code somehow? Or do you really mean you want to access them in a test case? RIDE and robot are two different things.

Comment: I am using the Robot Framework IDE (RIDE) to create keywords and Test cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a suite variable with `Set Suite Variable`, you can access the variable in your test cases like a normal variable. There's nothing else you need to do.

```
*** Test Cases ***
| Example 1
| | Set suite variable | ${message} | Hello, world

| Example 2
| | log | ${message}
```